# iCheck - set color of the siblings

Tags: javascript, jquery, icheck

I am using the jQuery library 'iCheck' for inputs and I am trying to set the color of the labels to green for those questions which were good answered. When I don't use iCheck everything works perfectly, but when I use that library, my script seems to have no effect. What am I doing wrong?

HTML document

```
<div class="radio" >
  {% if answer.is_valid == True %}
  <input type="radio" name="question-{{ question.id }}" id=" {{answer.text}}">
  {% else %}
  <input type="radio" name="question-{{ question.id }}" id="{{answer.text}}">
  {% endif %}
    <label><b>{{ answer.text }}</b></label>
</div>
```

JS

```
$('.check').click( function () {
    var score = 0
    var all = $('input[id^=" "]');
    var checked = $('input:checked');
    var good = $('input:checked[id^=" "]');

    checked.siblings().css('color', 'red');
    all.siblings().css('color', 'green');
    good.each ( function(){
        score += 1;
    })

    alert(score);
    score = 0;
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because `icheck` changes the DOM in such a way that your original input is not even visible anymore. Check the DOM browser to see that `iCheck` changed your

```
<input type="radio" name="question-{{ question.id }}" id=" {{answer.text}}">
```

To

```
<div class="iradio_flat-pink" aria-checked="false" aria-disabled="false" style="position: relative;">
<input type="radio" name="question-1" id="text" style="position: absolute; opacity: 0;">
<ins class="iCheck-helper" style="position: absolute; top: 0%; left: 0%; display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); border: 0px; opacity: 0; background-position: initial initial; background-repeat: initial initial;">
</ins>
</div>
```

Or something similar.
To change the color of the element you need to use the iCheck functions instead and give it a different class:

```
$('#input1').iCheck({
    radioClass: 'radio-green' //or something you like.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this!

```
$( document ).ready(function () {        
    if ($("input.flat")[0]) {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('input.flat').iCheck({
                checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_flat-blue',
                radioClass: 'iradio_flat-blue'
            });
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: What is the advantage of nested `$(document).ready()` functions?

Comment: It's only a example